# How to consume Azure function app from C# using Managed Service Identity as security feature?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am trying to call azure function app from ASP.NET MVC applicaton (AZURE AD authentication enabled) to consume the results. Based on the details mentioned in the below link, I was able to accomplish it but in this case there are two ways how the key is passed to the  in the call to ensure azure will process the request.

http://mario-loza.blogspot.com/2017/06/calling-azure-functions-from-c-with.html

Instead of the two ways mentioned in the link, can we use Managed Service Identity in the ASP.NET MVC application to access the Azure function app.

In this case I want to restrict the calls made to the azure function from an app that is already Azure AD authenticated.

Can anyone help me here by providing their inputs

Comment: Please refer to this [blog](https://jpd.ms/using-azure-managed-service-identities-with-your-apps-b979564ddf4) and StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49657387/azure-function-using-msi-error-requesting-token) if this helps.

Comment: Here my source is AAD enabled web app and target is azure function app. I am trying to access the azure function app from the AAD enabled web app using MSI instead of passing the secret code for the azure function app. Both the resources are within the same Azure subscription. I don't see anything mentioned in the links.

Comment: MSI function enable a security  way that to access the azure resources. If you want to call azure http  trigger function, function key is still needed. But you could use Azure SDK to get the function key from the code.